# Ruby Question: Is there any way to invoke a method like the selector in Objective-C

Tags: ruby

In Obj-C, the method to invoke can be decided at runtime using selector mechanism.

Is there anything similar in Ruby so that I can convert a method string into a method symbol at runtime and invoke it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the `send` method:

`obj.send(method_name)`, where `method_name` can be either a string or a symbol, will invoke the method with the given name on `obj`.

Any arguments you want to pass to the method, can be given as additional arguments to `send`, i.e. `obj.send(method_name, argument1, argument2)`.

Comment: Probably worth explaining how you pass arguments.

Comment: @sepp2k:Thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Checkout [Ruby Object Class send method](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000999).